# Testar igualdade de valores (data) em PHP

Tags: php, data

Olá, preciso testar se duas datas são iguais em PHP (data atual x último dia útil do mês), as duas são strings, mas não estou conseguindo obter o resultado utilizando o seguinte código:

```
 if(strcmp($ultimo, $hoje) == 0)
     echo "<br><br>As duas datas são iguais";
 else
     echo "<br><br>As duas datas são diferentes";
```

O cálculo para o último dia útil é o seguinte:

```
 $mes = 07;
 $ano = 2014;
 $dias = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes, $ano);
 $ultimo = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dias, $ano); 
 $dia = date("j", $ultimo);
 $dia_semana = date("w", $ultimo);
 if($dia_semana == 0){
   $dia--;
   $dia--;
 }
 if($dia_semana == 6)
   $dia--;
 $ultimo = (string)mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano);
```

Para a data atual:

```
$hoje= date("d/m/Y");
```

As duas datas mostram o resultado 31/07/2014, mas não estou conseguindo obter igualdade no resultado. Se alguém puder ajudar.

Comment: A variável `$ultimo` não está no formato com o qual você está comparando.

Answer (score 2):

Usando **date()**

```
<?php
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
 $mes = 07;
 $ano = 2014;
 $dias = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes, $ano);
 $ultimo = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dias, $ano); 
 $dia = date("j", $ultimo);
 $dia_semana = date("w", $ultimo);
 if($dia_semana == 0){
   $dia--;
   $dia--;
 }
 if($dia_semana == 6)
   $dia--;
 //repare que precisa-se de converter o mktime para date()
 $ultimo = date("d/m/Y",mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano));
 $hoje= date("d/m/Y"); 
 if ($ultimo==$hoje)
     echo "verdadeiro";
 else
     echo "falso";
```

**Para versões do PHP igual ou posteriores a 5.2**

DateTime:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Edmonton');
 //...
$ultimo = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '$dia-$mes-$ano',$timezone);
$hoje=  new DateTime(null, $timezone);
if ($ultimo==$hoje)
    echo "verdadeiro";
else
    echo "falso";
```

Comment: Lembrando que o `TimeZone` é opcional. Se não informado, o timezone padrão do servidor será utilizado.

Answer (score 0):

Faça a conversão das datas para **strtotime()** e faça a comparação, comparação em números inteiros fica mais fácil.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função strtotime para gerar um inteiro e então comparar, veja:

```
$dateIni   =   '01/08/2014';

$dateFim   =   '30/08/2014';

echo strtotime($dateIni)  ==  strtotime($dateFim) ? true : false;
```